# Popup menu uses original size of Image as anchor, instead of actual size

Tags: android, popup, imageview

I am having an image view displaying a nice image and opening a popup-menu on tap.
The images I use have different sizes in original, so the imageView has a static width.
However when I anchor the pop-up-menu at the imageView, it uses the original sized image as anchor, which results in very weird views. (Screenshots appended)
Of course I could size all images on the same size, but since the images are having sizes in px and not dp, it would lead to problems on screens with a different screen-resolution.
[image: Working fine with small picture]
[image: Misplaces with originally bigger picture]

Is this an error in my code or a bug of the pop-up menu? Wanted to file it as bug, but it´s pretty much impossible to find the place to do so either.

Here´s my xml for the imageView (image view having a default icon):

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/languageFlag"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/searchView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/searchView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/searchView"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_casino_24" />
```

Here´s my xml for the whole fragment (Just in case this matters):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="bi.deutsch_kirundi_app.fragments.DictionaryFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightgrey">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/languageFlag"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/searchView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/searchView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/searchView"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_casino_24" />

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/languageFlag"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
             >

        </SearchView>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/result_fragment"
            android:name="bi.deutsch_kirundi_app.fragments.dictionary.AllVocabularyFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchView"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_all_vocabulary" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

In the "onCreateView"-method of my fragment, I get the imageView, get the images ids and set the one for the corresponding language saved in SharedPreferences. (Logically)

```
languagePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.languageFlag)
        val sharedPreferences = view.context.getSharedPreferences(App.APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val lastChosenTranslationDirection = sharedPreferences.getInt(App.TRANSLAT_KEY, 0)
        val ids = view.context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.translation_direction_flags)
        images = Array(ids.size) {
            val imageId = resources.getIdentifier(ids[it], "drawable", activity?.packageName)
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.context, imageId)
        }
        languagePicker.setImageDrawable(images[lastChosenTranslationDirection])
```

Then I am setting the onclick-listener on the imageView (languagePicker) the following:

```
languagePicker.setOnClickListener {
            val dropDownMenu = PopupMenu(it.context, languagePicker)
            val languages = it.resources.getStringArray(R.array.translation_directions)
            for(index in languages.indices) {
                dropDownMenu.menu.add(0, index, index,
                        languages[index])
                dropDownMenu.show()
                dropDownMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this)
            }
        }
```

Seems fine to me, but maybe I am blinded. Is there a need to add some specific property to the imageview, so the size of the Drawable is also adapted?

**EDIT**: I don´t want the width of the PopUp-Menu to be changed. Rather I want the Popup-Menu to use the ImageView as anchor, not the originally sized image. As visible on the screenshot with the German Flag, it is pushed to the bottom instead of sticking to the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the `PopupMenu` item layout actually doesn't have anything to do with the size of the original images set on the `ImageView`. The item layouts for `PopupMenus` simply have a minimum default width, and I don't think you can change it.

I would suggest that you switch to using `Spinner`, `PopupWindow`, or `ListPopupWindow`. These allow you to set your own item layouts, so you can choose exactly how you want each item to look.

I believe the default item layout for a `Spinner` just has its width set to the widest item in the list, so that might be the easiest route:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner

Comment: The width of the pop up menu is not the problem. 
It´s just fine. 
The width I am referring to in the post is the width of the imageView. 
This is also working fine. As you can see, all images are the same size. But since the German flag has a bigger original image, the PopupMenu does not appear below the imageView, but way of at the bottom of the screen. (Actually where the original image would end.) That´s of course not supposed to happen.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. But now I don't see how setting all the images to the same size would cause problems at different resolutions.

Comment: And if there really is a reason you can't have uniform image sizes, you could just add a dummy `View` to serve as the anchor. Just place a `View` behind the `ImageView` so it's not visible but has the same place on screen.

Comment: Or just use an existing CountryCodePicker and avoid the issue altogether: https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject

Comment: Since image sizes are in px, different resolutions of screens should lead to different dp-sizes of the same image. (At least that´s, what I would expect.) 
But I also just made all of them the same size and hope now it won´t end up on some PixelArt-resolution phones, causing actual problems. :D